# Get Pdf Rest Sharp (GET)

Tags: c#, json, rest, pdf, sharp

I am testing a service to which you send a json and it returns a PDF with the data you sent it. I did tests with Insomnia as shown here:

[image: test with insomnia]

It works correctly, but trying to recover the file through code always generates an error. My code is the following:

```
var client = new RestClient("Api");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"QuotationId\": 0,\n\t\"QuotationName\": \"CasaLomas\",\n\t\"UserGUID\": \"75DB06AC-E349-4C47-A5AF-87EC63A9B8A9\",\n\t\"QuotedQuantity\": 5,\n\t\"TotalPrice\": 500,\n\t\"CopyEmail\": \"angelmg50@hotmail.com\",\n\t\"MaterialDetails\": [\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"SKU\": \"C05423082015140001\",\n\t\t\t\"Name\": \"PORC KONE WHITE MATE 60x30x1\",\n\t\t\t\"Quantity\": 1,\n\t\t\t\"Price\": 638.09,\n\t\t\t\"Amount\": 6380\n\t\t},\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"SKU\": \"C05423082015140001\",\n\t\t\t\"Name\": \"PORC KONE WHITE MATE 60x30x1\",\n\t\t\t\"Quantity\": 1,\n\t\t\t\"Price\": 638.09,\n\t\t\t\"Amount\": 6380\n\t\t},\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"SKU\": \"C05423082015140001\",\n\t\t\t\"Name\": \"PORC KONE WHITE MATE 60x30x1\",\n\t\t\t\"Quantity\": 1,\n\t\t\t\"Price\": 638.09,\n\t\t\t\"Amount\": 6380\n\t\t}\n\t]\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This connects correctly with the API but apparently the json has not been sent correctly. Any idea why this happens?

I created the json with dynamic and tried to send it.

```
dynamic cotizacion = new JObject();

cotizacion.QuotationId = 0;
cotizacion.QuotationName = "Casa lomas 3";
cotizacion.UserGUID = "75DB06AC-E349-4C47-A5AF-87EC63A9B8A9";
cotizacion.QuotedQuantity = 6;
cotizacion.TotalPrice = 456.12;
cotizacion.CopyEmail = "angelmg50@hotmail.com";
cotizacion.MaterialDetails = new JArray(new JObject(
  new JProperty("SKU", "C05423082015140001"),
  new JProperty("Name", "PORC KONE WHITE MATE 60x30x1"),
  new JProperty("Quantity", 1),
  new JProperty("Price", 638.09),
  new JProperty("Amount", 6380.30)));

var client = new RestClient("Api");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", cotizacion, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

But this does not work either.

When I print response.Content in console it shows me the following: "Message": "Internal error when trying to generate the PDF" Value can not be null. \ R \ nParameter name: source "," StatusCode ": 3," Result ": null, "ResultList": null}

Comment: \n \t \r tags are needed to be eliminated.

Comment: I did it, but it still does not work. Any other idea?

Comment: you always need to provide exception/error details in order to get help for your issues

Comment: The first idea is to never write JSON manually

Comment: I have edited my question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage

It seems like you are trying to add a parameter with the name `"application/json"`. You may need to specify the name of the parameter in the endpoint and use `AddObject` instead of `AddParameter`. We can help more if you can give us some more info on your endpoint.

Comment: The endpoint was provided to me only to consume it. I know it works because I did tests with Insomnia. The Endpoint receives the json that I send and returns a PDF with the information of that json in bytes.  Here is an example of what it receives and what it returns.

[link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9pJZ.png)